What methods can be used to distinguish the Kinoshita-Terasaka knot from the Conway knot?
The Kinoshita-Terasaka knot is famously hard to distinguish from the Conway knot because they share a host of similar invariants.
I was wondering if there is a text or a set of invariant measures I can be pointed towards that distinguishes between the two knots, and maybe generalises to distinguishing mutation between knots.
I am aware of the coloured HOMFLY-PT polynomial however beyond that I cannot find any other (known) way to distinguish between these knots.
Thanks!

Both 3-genus and 4-genus distinguish these two knots.
The 3-genus of the Kinoshita-Terasaka knot is 2, while the 3-genus of the Conway knot is 3. One computational way to deduce the genera of these knots is by computing their knot Floer homology.
The Kinoshita-Terasaka knot is slice, that is, it has 4-genus 0. Here's a picture of the knot with a slice disk (taken from Jennifer Hom's article Getting a handle on the Conway knot).

The Conway knot is famously not slice and has 4-genus 1, as proven by Lisa Piccirillo (reference).
